# Make: drop targets after recursion

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Make is a beautiful and powerful tool for wide and sundry use.  I love it, and this is only a detail.

Suppose I have a recursive make recipe defined as follows:

```
submake-cmd:
  make ${SUBMAKEGOALS} -C foo

# where I have derived ${SUBMAKEGOALS} earlier
```

And here is the crux: I can either set the make interface up like so...

```
$: make submake-cmd SUBMAKEGOALS="foo bar"
```

-- OR --

```
# preferably 
make submake-cmd foo bar biz baz
```

---

The only problem is that if I calculate the `${SUBMAKEGOALS}`, then I am forced to write the `submake-cmd` rule like so in order to avoid unpredictable behavior:

```
submake-cmd:
  make ${SUBMAKEGOALS} -C foo
  exit 1
```

Such that make will exit, and I will see make exit with an error.

---

There must be some way to clear out the make targets or indicate that `make` has completed successfully when using make recursion...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what you want to do.  However, there is no variable or function that can force make to believe that some target has already been built.  Only by make trying to build it, can that be done.  If I understood more exactly what you wanted to do there's probably a way to do it, but that is not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> preferably
>
> `make submake-cmd foo bar biz baz`

You're probably overthinking something. If you want to pass an unknown number of targets to submake then it could be done like this:

```
ifneq ($(sub),)
.DEFAULT:
    $(MAKE) -C $(sub) $@
endif
```

And then: `make sub=dir1 foo; make sub=dir2 bar biz baz`etc. (I assume the root makefile does not contain any of foo/bar/biz/baz of its own; if it's not so, then you have to patch these rules appropriately).